# How do you get the latest version of TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

How do you get the latest version of TortoiseHg on Windows, I don't see a 'Check for updates' link on the context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The About TortoiseHg option on the context menu will bring up a window telling you if there is a new version available.

You could always check on [the website](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) too.

Comment: Weird I am on version 0.8 and I don't see an Update option in the About box

Comment: visit the website then. You are about a dozen versions behind.

Comment: I posted this question, just because I didn't see the Update option. Maybe it never existed on that particular release. Thanks

Comment: @Joe: They have a new release around the beginning of each month, by the way.